# Cobertura report showing lines not covered

Tags: junit, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm using Cobertura and Maven to make the report, but i have a question about the report.

[image: Cobertura Report]

Here are my Unit test

```
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerSuccesPresenceParametreMinimum() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    boolean presence = validateur.validerPresenceParametreMinimum(usager);
    assertTrue(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecPresenceParametreMinimumIdentifiantNomPrenomNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    usager.setIdentifiants(null);
    usager.setPrenom(null);
    usager.setNom(null);
    boolean presence = validateur.validerPresenceParametreMinimum(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecPresenceParametreMinimumIdentifiantsNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    usager.setIdentifiants(null);
    boolean presence = validateur.validerPresenceParametreMinimum(usager);
    assertTrue(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecPresenceParametreMinimumUsagerNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = null;
    boolean presence = validateur.validerPresenceParametreMinimum(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerSuccesTypeIdentifiants() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    boolean presence = validateur.validerTypeIdentifiants(usager);
    assertTrue(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecTypeIdentifiantsUsagerNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = null;
    boolean presence = validateur.validerTypeIdentifiants(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecTypeIdentifiantNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    usager.getIdentifiants().get(0).setTypeIdentifiant(null);
    boolean presence = validateur.validerTypeIdentifiants(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecIdentifiantNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    usager.getIdentifiants().get(0).setIdentifiant(null);
    boolean presence = validateur.validerTypeIdentifiants(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
@Test
public void testValiderUsagerEchecTypeIdentifiantIdentifiantNull() {
    UsagerDTO usager = this.creerUsagerDTO();
    usager.getIdentifiants().get(0).setTypeIdentifiant(null);
    usager.getIdentifiants().get(0).setIdentifiant(null);
    boolean presence = validateur.validerTypeIdentifiants(usager);
    assertFalse(presence);
}
```

I make the unit test to be able to cover the 3 lines in red. But I do not know why they are still there like they are not covered. And, as you can see, they are executed a x times.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on Cobertura, but normally if you hover on the red highlighted part (around the bold number) you get a popup with some more information

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say much. "Line 42: Conditional coverage 75 % (3/4) [each condition: 100 %, 50 %].". I don't even know what does it mean.